# Simulate Chrome link-opening behavior in Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox

Chrome opens links in a new tab by default, however if opens a new window if one doesn't exist yet on the current desktop. Firefox has an option to open links in a new tab by default instead of a new window by default too, however, it occasionally trips on some sites (e.g., sites that use a "link to external site" and sites that use javascript to do the redirect instead of HTML links)

[image]

Is there a way to get Firefox to behave like Chrome in this regard?

Comment: Try this: [kb.mozillazine.org > Browser.link.open > newwindow.restriction](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction)

Comment: @BlindSpots I tried following editing the config that article mentioned, yet I don't see any change. Case in point, clicking the `APIMessageComponent` link on [this site](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserSelectMenuComponent?scrollTo=data) on Chrome opens it in a new tab as expected, however Firefox opens it in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main preferences in `about:config` that control new window/tab behavior in Firefox. You may need to configure a specific one based on your desired behavior.

#### browser.link.open_newwindow

[`browser.link.open_newwindow` has three options.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow)<sup>[1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow)</sup>

> - `1` - Open links, that would normally open in a new window, in the current tab/window.
> - `2` - Open links, that would normally open in a new window, in a new window.
> - `3` - Open links, that would normally open in a new window, in a new tab in the current window.

#### browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction

Firefox opens a new window when a window size is specified.

You can disable this with the `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction` preference set to `0` in `about:config`.

[`browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction` has three options.](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction)<sup>[2](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction)</sup>

> - `0` - Divert all links according to browser.link.open_newwindow.
> - `1` - Do not divert any links (browser.link.open_newwindow will have no effect).
> - `2` - Divert all links according to browser.link.open_newwindow, unless the new window specifies how it should be displayed.

Full explanation [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/s70iq5/preventdisable_opening_new_windows/)<sup>[3](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/s70iq5/preventdisable_opening_new_windows/)</sup>:

> Most links directed toward new windows are automatically diverted to new tabs, but Firefox usually makes an exception for scripted popups with certain features specified, such as width and height. There is a separate preference for that. I have the details on my test page:
>
> https://www.jeffersonscher.com/res/popit.html

If you follow that link, you can test the 3 scenarios. The 3rd one:

> Link with onclick="window.open()" (width and height set to 800x600) — opens in a new window by default*

opens a new window, but after the new window restriction preference is changed it opens in a new tab.

---

Sources:

<sup>[1](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow)</sup>http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow

<sup>[2](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction)</sup>http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction

<sup>[3](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/s70iq5/preventdisable_opening_new_windows/)</sup>https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/s70iq5/preventdisable_opening_new_windows/

https://www.jeffersonscher.com/res/popit.html

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1226151

Comment: I tried following editting the config you mentioned, yet I don't see any change. Case in point, clicking on the `APIMessageComponent` link on [this site][https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/UserSelectMenuComponent?scrollTo=data) on Chrome opens it in a new tab, however Firefox opens it in a new window.

Comment: @404NameNotFound It opens in a new tab for me. Just to confirm, have you restarted Firefox after changing the setting?

Comment: I believe I have, I closed all windows I have open. Before and after, still opens in a new window.

Comment: What values do you have for these preferences in about:config? `browser.link.open_newwindow`, `browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction`, and `browser.link.open_newwindow.override.external`

Comment: `2`, `0`, and `-1` respectively: [`about:config` settings](https://i.imgur.com/AoegDSb.png)

Comment: Try switching `browser.link.open_newwindow` to `3`.

Comment: While that does solve it for the links, now _all_ links redirect to an existing tab instead of opening a new window in a different desktop (e.g., having a window open in Desktop 1 and clicking on a link in Desktop 2 brings me to Desktop 1 instead of opening a new window in Desktop 2, as Chrome does)